# Update profile picture in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm new to react so pardon any mistake.
I want to update user profile picture but i dont know how can i make a clickable image(`variable name ->"avatar" in code`) which previews and then update(in database also), if we click save.

Can someone help me adding a clickable image that previews and updates the from and database as well.
**If we cannot make clickable image, a separate button for upload and save will also be fine.**
Let me know if you want more info about code.
the code i have:

```
import React from 'react';
import ProfileBanner from '../ProfileBanner';
import coverSrc from 'assets/img/generic/4.jpg';
//import avatar from 'assets/img/team/2.jpg';
import { Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import ProfileSettings from './ProfileSettings';
//import ExperiencesSettings from './ExperiencesSettings';
//import EducationSettings from './EducationSettings';
//import AccountSettings from './AccountSettings';
import BillingSettings from './BillingSettings';
import ChangePassword from './ChangePassword';
import DangerZone from './DangerZone';
import axios from 'axios';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import { useEffect ,useState,useRef} from 'react';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';


 const Settings = () => {
  
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    avatar: '',
    });

  //const { avatar} = formData;
  
  const cookies = new Cookies();
  const user_id = cookies.get('xyz');

  useEffect(async () => {
   
    //e.preventDefault();
    const config = {
      
      headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",

      },
  };

  try {
    
    const { data } = await axios.post(

        `/api/auth/ImageRetrieve`,
        {
          user_id
        },
        config

    );
    
    setFormData({
      avatar:data.link
    });
  } 
  catch (error) {
    toast.success('Something went wrong', {
    theme: 'colored'
  });

  }
  
}, []);
  
  

  return (
    <>
   
      <ProfileBanner>
        
        <div> 
        
           <ProfileBanner.Header
          coverSrc={coverSrc}
          avatar={formData.avatar}
          className="mb-8"
          /> 
          
           
         </div>
        
        
        
      </ProfileBanner>
      
      <Row className="g-3">
        <Col lg={8}>
          <ProfileSettings />
          {/*<ExperiencesSettings />
          <EducationSettings />}*/}
          <br></br>
          <ChangePassword />
        </Col>
        <Col lg={4}>
          <div className="sticky-sidebar">
           {/* <AccountSettings />*/}
            <BillingSettings />
            
            <DangerZone />
          </div>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </>
      );
    };
    
    export default Settings;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can basically add `onClick` property to any native element, so

```
  <span onClick={()=>{ /*put here some code that change the coverSrc state*/}}>
      <ProfileBanner.Header
         coverSrc={coverSrc}
         avatar={formData.avatar}
         className="mb-8"
       />
 </span>
```

you can create a popup to enter new pic URL and than on-close update that state.

Comment: you're using a library that just get url, so you can handle the state of the `yourSource`. the moment you'll change that  - the pic will be changed, so you can wrap that element with just a `span` tag or so and attach the onClick to the tag

Comment: Not working,i need more details and code

Comment: Put a `console.log` inside the onClick callback. that should print the log on each click. now you will need to build a popup, make that appear on that click, there let the user choose new pic

Comment: Can you remove your answer, Ive putted this question on bounty but  getting having trouble to get more answers people are thinking its already been answered.

Comment: It's fine to ask for more information, but it's weird to ask him to delete the given answer saying they'll think my question has been answered.

Comment: You have the answer here. I'm not going to write all the rest of the code for you, so do the rest of the ppl here. You're not getting any new answers because this is the right answer, and that should work. If not - explain in more detail WHAT didn't work and we will try to help. you'll have to write the popup yourself or use a library, that's another question.

Comment: @COdersLime Yosi wrote an answer, just for you, so don't you ask them to delete it! If you're unhappy with Yosi's answer, you should ask them what you're missing, they're able & willing (so far) to help you. The reason you have trouble getting more answers is becaus it's not clear in what way Yosi's answer is lacking. Just putting a bounty on your question won't make it clearer. But you could've just told Yosi what you're missing, that bounty reputation was completely wasted.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of the problem, I think you are looking something like this -

```
 const [selectedAvatar, setSelectedAvatar] = useState();
 const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    avatar: '',
  });

  useEffect(() => {
      if (!selectedAvatar) {
        setFormData({...formData, avatar: ''});
        return;
      }

      const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(selectedAvatar);
     
      //DB call to save objectUrl into the DB

      setFormData({...formData, avatar: objectUrl});
      
      return () => URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
  }, [selectedAvatar]);

  const onSelectFile = e => {
      if (!e.target.files || !e.target.files.length) {
          setSelectedAvatar('');
          return;
      }

      setSelectedAvatar(e.target.files[0]);
  }

  return (
      <div>
          <input type='file' onChange={onSelectFile} />
          {!!selectedAvatar &&  <div> 
                                  <ProfileBanner.Header
                                     coverSrc={coverSrc}
                                     avatar={formData.avatar}
                                     className="mb-8"
                                   /> 
                                 </div> 
          }
      </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import ReactProfile from "react-profile";
import "react-profile/themes/default.min.css";

function App() {
  return <ReactProfile src="./your-image.png" />;
}

export default App;
```